# How to use behaviorSubject when removing item from array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-observable

I have angular 8 application.

And I have two components, like child - parent relationship. So I remove the item from the child, but then the item is still visible in the parent(list of items). Only after page refresh the item is gone from the list.

So I have this service:

```
export class ItemListService {
 _updateItemChanged = new Subject<any>();
 _removeItemChanged = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

  constructor() {}
}
```

and this is item.ts - child:

```
openRemoveDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ItemRemoveDialogComponent, {
      width: '500px',
      height: '500px',
      data: {
        dossierId: this.dossier.id,
        item: this.item,
        attachments: this.item.attachments
      }
    });

    this.itemListService._removeItemChanged.next(this.item.title);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result === true) {
        this.router.navigate(['/dossier', this.dossier.id]);

      }
    });
  }
```

and this is the view.ts(item list) - parent: so in this component the refresh has to be made

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.show = !this.router.url.includes('/item/');

    this.itemlistService._updateItemChanged.subscribe(data => {
      const index = this.dossierItems.findIndex(a => a.id === data.id);
      this.dossierItems[index] = data;
    });

    this.itemlistService._removeItemChanged.subscribe(data => {
     // this.dossierItems.pop(); What I have to fill in here?

    });
```

So what I have to change?

Thank you

and this is the remove function:

```
  remove() {
    this.dossierItemService.deleteDossierItem(this.data.dossierId, this.data.item.id)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.dialogRef.close(true);
      }, (error) => {
        const processedErrors = this.errorProcessor.process(error);
        this.globalErrors = processedErrors.getGlobalValidationErrors();
    });
  }
```

I have it now like this:

```
remove() {
    this.dossierItemService.deleteDossierItem(this.data.dossierId, this.data.item.id)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.dialogRef.close(true);
        this.itemListService._removeItemChanged.next(true);
      }, (error) => {
        const processedErrors = this.errorProcessor.process(error);
        this.globalErrors = processedErrors.getGlobalValidationErrors();
    });
  }
```

and in the view.ts, like ths:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.itemlistService._removeItemChanged.subscribe(update => update === true ? this.dossierItems : '');
}
```

but still the list will not be refreshed

Comment: Not sure I understand the flow. One thing though looks wrong to me: in method `openRemoveDialog()` the call `this.itemListService._removeItemChanged.next(this.item.title)` may belong inside `if (result === true)` block in same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new reference to your array for Angular to update the screen like this

```
this.itemlistService._removeItemChanged.subscribe(data => { 
    // this.dossierItems.pop(); What I have to fill in here?
    this.dossierItems = this.dossierItems.filter(e => e.title !== data);
});
```